# Functions do not run together in Python

Tags: python

Hello I am creating a small program that will take the multiples from a number and then determine which numbers are prime numbers. One problem I am having is that I am getting the following error when I run the program

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'prime_number' was never awaited prime_number(multiples)
```

Here is my code: I am not sure what I am doing wrong as the multiples list populates with all the potential prime numbers, but the prime_number function appears to be skipped over entirely.

```
max = 20
num = 20
multiples = []
prime_numbers = []
def all_multiples(max):
    """finds all whole number multiples of max variable integer 
    and appends to multiples list"""
    for x in range(2, num):
        if max%x == 0:
            print(str(x) + " is a multiple!")
            multiples.append(x)
all_multiples(max)

def prime_number(multiples):
    """filters out multiples list for prime numbers and appends to prime_numbers list"""
    for x in multiples:
        if x/2 == 0:
            print("not a prime number")
        else:
            prime_numbers.append(x)
            print(str(x) + "is a prime number")
prime_number(multiples)
print(multiples)
print(prime_numbers)
```

Comment: I'm not getting any exceptions when I run your code (i.e. no `RuntimeWarning`). How are you invoking it? What version of python are you using?

Comment: As a side note, the way you're finding prime number isn't correct. A prime number `x` is not defined such that `x/2 != 0`.

Comment: oops I meant to put a % in that, thanks for the catch. I am running it through Visual Studio Code and I have python 3.7. Also can you explain why my if max%x == 0 works the way it works? Shouldn't it be max//x %0?

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems to run fine now...I don't know what the problem was in Visual Studio Code, but I didn't change anything...